# $g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \rceil x^n$, find $g(\frac{1}{3})$

Tags: calculus

Let $g(x)=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \rceil x^n$ (the ceil function). Then evaluate $g(\frac{1}{3})$.

This function promptly evaluates to $\frac{1}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$. (by the way would this be correct)? I substituted $\frac{1}{3}$ for x and got $\frac{27}{16}$.

I mainly wanted to check if the equation $\frac{1}{x^3-x^2-x+1}$ is the same as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \rceil x^n$. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Hint: if you can find a formula for $h(u) = 1+2u+3u^2+4u^3+\cdots$, then $g(x) = (1+x)h(x^2)$.

Comment: Hint:re Greg Martin's comment, which focuses on a tricky topic if you haven't been properly trained, if $S(u) = (1 + u + u^2 + \cdots)$, how would you evaluate $S(u)[1 + u + u^2 + \cdots]$?

Comment: Please do not ask the same question again: see [this meta thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32514/can-i-repost-any-old-question-of-mine). Instead, edit your question to improve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation seems to be correct:

\begin{align}
g(x)=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+\ldots &=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)x^{2n}+x\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)x^{2n}\\
&=(1+x)\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)x^{2n}
\end{align}

The function $h(y)=\sum^\infty_{n=0}(n+1)y^n=\sum^\infty_{n=1}ny^{n-1}=\frac{d}{dy}(1-y)^{-1}=(1-y)^{-2}$

So what you have is
$g(x)=\frac{(1+x)}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2(1+x)}=\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)}=\frac{1}{1-x-x^2+x^3}$