# Convergence of a summation function

Tags: calculus, summation

Let $g(x)=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lceil {\frac{n+1}{2}} \rceil x^n$ (the ceil function). What is the radius of convergence of this function?

I attempted this question by using the root test: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^{n+1} \frac{n+2}{2}}{\frac{1}{x^n}\frac{2}{n+1}}$. i simplified the terms and got limit $= 1$. So the radius of convergence is 1?

Comment: Didn't you already ask this here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4085135/gx-sum-n-0-infty-lceil-fracn12-rceil-xn-find-g-frac13

Comment: @KentaS no, that's a different question altogether. That one was to calculate some values of g, like $g(2)$. This one seeks to find the radius of convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radius of convergence is $1$.

> We can see this also by simplifying the series $g(x)$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{g(x)}&=1+x+2x^2+2x^3+3x^4+3x^5+\cdots\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\lceil\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rceil x^n\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\lceil\frac{2n+1}{2}\right\rceil x^{2n}
> +\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left\lceil\frac{2n+2}{2}\right\rceil x^{2n+1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^{2n}
> +\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1) x^{2n+1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^{2n}}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> and from (1) can we show for instance with the ratio test the radius of convergence is $1$.

We can also go on with calculation and obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{g(x)}&=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)x^{2n}\\
&=(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n 1\right)x^{2n}\\
&=(1+x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty x^{2n}\\
&=(1+x)\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\\
&=(1+x)\frac{1}{1-x^2}\,\frac{1}{1-x^2}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(1+x)(1-x)^2}}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
We observe directly from (2) we have a product of three geometric series with radius of convergence equal to $1$.